# Background Music WP

Tags: plugins, php, javascript

this may be a stupid topic but a client has commissioned me this: some music to be included in some pages. I can not find any plugins to help me do this. Do you know anyone?
Now, I was thinking if you could do with php by creating a simple plugin or using js with a small script. What's better? Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: I don't think several modern browsers even *allow* auto-playing audio without the user clicking a button first.

Comment: Asking for plugin recommendations is considered to be Off Topic. This question would be better asked over at [The Official WordPress Forums](https://wordpress.org/support/forums/)

Answer (score 1):

I would do your best to talk them out of it.

https://moz.com/blog/how-to-convince-a-client-their-site-doesnt-need-music

If all else fails

`<audio src="horse.ogg" controls>
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>`

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_src.asp